# Second BroadCast Receiver Does Not Run

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I Write A Program That Want To Run Two BroadCast Receiver Class in One Alarm Manager .
first Class is MyReceiver and Second is RequestReciever ...
First One is Run But Second One is Not Run ...Why? Can You Help Me...
my alarm manger calling

```
 private void workingAlaramManager() {
    //enable onRecieve method in broadcast reciever to report and get action in listener
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    Intent requestIntent=new Intent(getContext(),RequestReciever.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentRequest = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, requestIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000, pendingIntent);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000, pendingIntentRequest);

}
```

my first Class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}
private GPSLocation gpsLocation;
private ApiManager apiManager;
private Activity activity;
private Context context;
private SharedPref sharedPref;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context=context;
    activity=new MainAccountActivity();
    apiManager = new ApiManager();
    sharedPref=new SharedPref(apiManager.deliveryPartner,apiManager.deliveryPartner.deliveryBike,context);
    sharedPref.loadData();
    getLatAndLng();
    getDataTime();
    requestToReportDeliverySituation();
}
```

second one that does not run :(

public class RequestReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public RequestReciever() {

```
}

private ApiManager apiManager;
private Activity activity;
private Context context;
private SharedPref sharedPref;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    activity = new MainAccountActivity();

    apiManager = new ApiManager();
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(apiManager.deliveryPartner, apiManager.deliveryPartner.deliveryBike, context);
    sharedPref.loadData();

    sendCheckDeliveryRequest();

}
```

help me please my friends ...

Comment: is RequestReciever added in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: also, there's a typo on `RequestReciever`, it should be `RequestReceiver`, make sure it matches the name added in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thanks . it helps very much :)

Comment: I'll add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that there are no typos and all of your receivers are registered in `AndroidManifest.xml`.